# Loop through each div of containers and compare the height index wise

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, foreach, each

Really sorry if there is any mistake in typo for title. But I need help in looping through 2 main divs and their child divs too. Here is the code sample:

```
<div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">Content 1</div>
    <div class="columns">Content 2</div>
    <div class="columns">Content 3</div>
</div>
<div class="containers">
    <div class="columns">Content 1</div>
    <div class="columns">Content 2</div>
    <div class="columns">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

What I need is that jquery loop through first .containers and get the height of first child and then loop to second .containers and get the height of first child and compare both height and apply which one is max height to both first elements of .containers.
Now go to second indexes of .containers, compare the height and apply maximum height to both second indexes and so on.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the jQuery documentation. For example, the `map()` entry has a working demo of exactly what you want to do: https://api.jquery.com/map/#example-2

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are correct but in my case your recommendation is not suitable as I need to get the height of same index div under different parents and compare the height and apply which height is maximum to both divs of same index under different parent.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I hope you got my point. Let me explain more:
if content 1 in first .containers has height 100px and content 1 in second .containers has height 80px then I want to apply 100px(max height) to content 1 of both .containers
In your recommend i see that I can set same height of all siblings under same parent.
In my case I need to move index wise with different parents

Comment: As you've not provided an attempt, can you be more specific regarding exactly which part you're having difficulty with?   eg looping through containers' children?  Knowing which index you're on?  (jquery [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) provides an 'index')  Getting heights of elements?   Comparing/getting max height?  Applying the height?

Comment: @freedomn-m Comparing/getting max height? with loop

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/each/ to loop, then get the other using each's index.  comparing/getting max height from @RoryMcCrossan 's link `this.height( Math.max.apply( this, maxHeight ) )`

Comment: Are both `.containers` guaranteed to have equal number of `.columns`?

Comment: @ruleboy21 Yes equal number of .columns

Comment: As I've applied the following code:

`
jQuery(".containers").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find(".columns").each(function(index) {
   var colHeight = jQuery(this).outerHeight();
   console.log("Current index is " + index);
  });
 });
`

Comment: I'm getting index as per required: 0 1 2 0 1 2
Can anyone help me that how can I compare now the height of columns which are index 0 and apply max height?
and same with next index and so on.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let $container2Columns = $('#container2 .columns');

    $('#container1 .columns').each(function(i){
        let $relatedColumn = $container2Columns.eq(i);
        let maxHeight      = Math.max($(this).height(), $relatedColumn.height());

        $(this).height(maxHeight);
        $relatedColumn.height(maxHeight);
    });
});
```

```css
.columns {
    width: 100px;
    background: #000;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers" id="container1">
    <div class="columns" style="height: 100px;">Content 1</div>
    <div class="columns" style="height: 400px;">Content 2</div>
    <div class="columns" style="height: 300px;">Content 3</div>
</div>
<div class="containers" id="container2">
    <div class="columns" style="height: 150px;">Content 1</div>
    <div class="columns" style="height: 200px;">Content 2</div>
    <div class="columns" style="height: 300px;">Content 3</div>
</div>
```